# I am having trouble installing libasound

Tags: raspbian

So I have gone to portaudio2 and it says:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev
```

It says 1 newly installed..

??  what directory do I call:   `./configure && make`

Comment: where did you download the software to? is libasound what you ae trying to install or is this a dependency of another package? Normally apt-get installs a compiled binary, where configure and make are used to build from source.

Comment: so i am trying to install an amatuer radio program called FLDIGI.  As I go and try to configure fldigi, it says no package portaudio-2.0 found.  (package requirements portaudio-2.0 >=19) So portaudio2.0 website instructions say:  sudo -apt-get install libasound-dev.  when that is completed, I try to ./configure FLDIGI again, and it still says portaudio-2.0 still not found

Comment: What website specifically? Are you following a tutorial? Please edit your question and add the details where they belong in your question, not in your comments.

Comment: Try this: sudo apt-get install libportaudio2 libportaudio-dev

Answer (score 0):

If you installed software using `apt`, there is no need to then configure and compile the software. It already did that step on its own through the install. You can use the command below to check that it installed.

```
ldconfig -p | grep libasound-dev
```